# I can not install a python package with pip on ubuntu18

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I install a python package with this `pip install pyScss`
but i get this error:

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyScss

```
Using cached pyScss-1.3.5.tar.gz (123 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oa7i3j7x/pyScss/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oa7i3j7x/pyScss/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-oa7i3j7x/pyScss/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oa7i3j7x/pyScss/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-oa7i3j7x/pyScss/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

ubuntu:18
python:3.6
please help me

Comment: From [here](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/issues/57) and [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/CHANGES.rst), it seems there is a problem/change with the latest release of setuptools - you may try to install a slightly older version of setuptools and then retry.

Comment: `pip install -U "setuptools<46"`

Comment: @phd this command solved my problem,thank you!

Comment: The above command mentioned by @phd:  `pip install -U "setuptools<46"`  solved the problem on windows too. Thanks!